# Paint.Net Updater Source or Component availability

Tags: open-source, paint.net

Yes, I see that paint.net no longer provides source code. Understood. But does anyone know what updater Paint.Net uses? Is it home grown? Or available as a separate componenet, maybe open source or can be licensed? We have an internal enterprise windows app it would be perfect for.

Comment: Thanks Giorgi and pyrochild. Both good answers that I'll pursue. I've also since found a Hanselminutes podcast in which Rick Brewster talks in depth about the Paint.Net installer http://www.hanselminutes.com/default.aspx?showID=156

Comment: see https://code.google.com/p/openpdn/ for the source code

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it's home-grown. Also note that Paint.NET updates very simply - by uninstalling the old version, then installing the new one.

If you can find Paint.NET 3.36 or older's source, it's still under the MIT license.

You could also post on the Paint.NET forum and Rick Brewster might give you the relevant portions of code or give you permission to use Reflector'd code.

His reason for closing the source was because of people ripping off the whole program. If all you're interested in is the updater, this is obviously not your goal and he'd likely be open to it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which one is used by Pain.Net but this one is quite powerful: [.NET Client Applications: .NET Application Updater Component](http://windowsclient.net/articles/appupdater.aspx)

Comment: This hasn't been updated since 2002 so I'm a little wary of using it